# How to output all first elements from all keys of a dictionary of lists of tuples?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

A snippet from my dictionary `my_emotions` looks like this:

```
   {'art': [(2135, ['anticipation', 'joy', 'sadness', 'surprise'])],
     'bad': [(7542, ['anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'sadness'])],
     'beautiful': [(4000, ['joy']), (4425, ['joy'])],
     'boy': [(777, ['disgust']), (2634, ['disgust']), (4442, ['disgust'])],
     'ceremony': [(2948, ['joy', 'surprise'])],
     'child': [(4263, ['anticipation', 'joy'])],
     'detention': [(745, ['sadness']),
                   (3461, ['sadness']),
                   (3779, ['sadness']),
                   (4602, ['sadness'])],...]}
```

I am aiming to output all the first numbers of every tuple that occur in every key into a list.

So far I've tried this:

```
for key in sorted(my_emotions.keys()):
    auto_emotion_indices = [].append(my_emotions[key][0][0])
```

but it outputs `None`.

I tried printing the output to see what I'm getting, using:

```
for key in sorted(my_emotions.keys()):
    auto_emotion_indices = [].append(my_emotions[key][0][0])
```

which outputs the part of the dictionary that I want (the numbers aka indices), but only the first ones when there's multiple occurances for a key.

E.g. for the key `detention`: I only get `745`, but not `3461`, `3779` etc...

A desired output would be:

```
my_list = [2135, 7542, 4000, 4425, 777, 2634, 4442, 2948, 4263, 745, 3461, 3779, 4602...]
```

What should I add to also include the rest of those numbers into my list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `list.append()` is an inplace operation and it returns `None`

Comment: I think what you want might be `[y[0] for x in my_emotions.values() for y in x]`

Comment: `'boy': [(777, ['disgust']), (2634, ['disgust']), (4442, ['disgust'])]` lol

Comment: @grantmccloskey lol, yeah, sorry - it was automatically generated. I deleted the most disturbing ones from the example above tbh ^^

Comment: @pault it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining my_emotions as:

```
my_emotions = {'art': [(2135, ['anticipation', 'joy', 'sadness', 'surprise'])],
        'bad': [(7542, ['anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'sadness'])],
        'beautiful': [(4000, ['joy']), (4425, ['joy'])],
        'boy': [(777, ['disgust']), (2634, ['disgust']), (4442, ['disgust'])],
        'ceremony': [(2948, ['joy', 'surprise'])],
        'child': [(4263, ['anticipation', 'joy'])],
        'detention': [(745, ['sadness']),
                      (3461, ['sadness']),
                      (3779, ['sadness']),
                      (4602, ['sadness'])]}
```

This **pythonic** line will do the trick:

```
my_list = [number for emotion in sorted(my_emotions.keys()) for number, _ in my_emotions[emotion]]
```

A less **pythonic** way is to do it with two for loops:

```
my_list = []
for emotion in sorted(my_emotions.keys()):
    for number, _ in my_emotions[emotion]:
        my_list.append(number)
```

If you want to check what is being added just insert a print statement in the inner loop. In both cases the **output** is:

```
[2135, 7542, 4000, 4425, 777, 2634, 4442, 2948, 4263, 745, 3461, 3779, 4602]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    auto_emotion_indices = []

    for keys in  sorted(my_emotions.keys()):
        for item in my_emotions[keys]:
            auto_emotion_indices.append(item[0])

    print(auto_emotion_indices)
```

Comment: Please include a short explanation of your code. Code-only answers are rarely helpful to future visitors and usually get deleted. StackOverflow isn't just about helping the OP, it's about building a Q&A resource for future people with the same problem.